# Confusion with Sorted Set Java

Tags: java, collections, sortedset

I have implemented a sorted set for user defined class and also implemented compareTo method to user defined class with Comparable interface. Now my requirement is if a character (i.e a to z) already exist then increment the frequency of character other wise sort the input according to their frequency.

```
String s = "abc"; // or "aaaab"  or any set of string between [ a - z ]
SortedSet<FreequencyIndex> sortedSet = new TreeSet<FreequencyIndex>();
    FreequencyIndex  symbol;
    for(int index = s.length() - 1; index >=0 ; index--){                            
        symbol = new FreequencyIndex(s.charAt(index), index, 0);            
        sortedSet.add(symbol);            
    }

System.out.println(sortedSet);
```

User defined class:

```
 class FreequencyIndex implements Comparable<FreequencyIndex>{
    char symbol;
    int index;
    int frequency;

    public FreequencyIndex(char newSymbol, int newIndex, int newFrequency){
        this.symbol = newSymbol;
        this.index = newIndex;
        this.frequency = newFrequency;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.symbol + " "+ this.frequency;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(FreequencyIndex f2){            
        if(this.symbol == f2.symbol){       
            f2.frequency++;
            return 0;
        }
        else            
        if(this.frequency > f2.frequency)
            return 1;
        else            
            return -1;  


    }
}
```

1. For the input S = "a" -> Sorted set would be [ a 0] but it's giving [a, 1]
2. For the input S = "ab" -> Sorted set would be [ a 0, b 0] but it's giving [a 0, b 1]
3. For the input S = "aba" -> Sorted set would be [ b 0, a 2] but it's giving [b 0, a 2]
4. For the input S = "aab" -> Sorted set would be [ b 0, a 2] but it's giving [a 1, b 1]

What I am missing here, could some one explain me?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `compareTo` should **not** have side effects.

Comment: What is s?  you haven't included the definition/initialisation of s.

Comment: s is string with different set of characters. eg: s = "aab" or "babcz" anything.

Comment: You are misusing sorted set. You can't sort by one property (frequency) and determinate equality by another property (symbol).

Comment: Also you need to write equals and hashCode methods if you are changing compareTo. But there are many problems with what you're doing.

Comment: In case you did not understand Eran's comment: Your `compareTo` method is doing `f2.frequency++` which means that it is modifying the content of the object that `f2` refers to. It must not do that. The `compareTo` method should not modify the objects it is comparing. You will get unpredictable behavior if you do that.

Comment: Thank you so much all of your inputs.

Comment: I think the very sort by frequency is a bad idea here. I don't think you need it during the frequency check, making it also inefficient. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `SortedSet` is a set that has some kind of sorting, and the most notorious one is a `TreeSet`. However, the sort is also important for finding out if a node is already there when calling `add`. Thus your solution where you sort by something different than the symbol breaks it.

Also, when you add something to any kind of set, be it `TreeSet`, `HashSet` or pretty much any other set, you are not supposed to modify the object, or at least, its fields that are used for comparison. That means, if you change the object somehow, methods like `equals`, `compareTo` or `hashCode` should still return the same values or your set doesn't work properly, and it can even cause duplicates to appear.

In your situation, the cleanest solution would be not to use `FrequencyIndex` as a key in anything and use a `Map<Character, FrequencyIndex>` for search by the symbol. Unless you need the sorted set multiple times during the process of adding new elements, you could just sort it after you complete the frequency check, and the following code could do it with said map quite easily, using Java 8 streams:

```
map.values().stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(FrequencyIndex::getFrequency))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The mentioned getter for frequency - I think you should add getters to the FrequencyIndex class.

**Efficiency** might actually be better with that - there is no reordering during the frequency check and it is all only done once, on a rather small set compared to the input size.

Comment: That's great inputs and really appreciated your time.